# Meaning of the passé composé with être

Tags: verbes, passé-composé

Is être in the passé composé really nothing but an auxillary verb, or does it cause some sense of the present perfect to be evoked?

For example, to my foreign ears, I can't help but automatically translate `je suis mort` to English `I am dead` or Spanish `Estoy muerto`. But I'm wondering if to French native speakers `je suis mort` really just means `I died`/`yo morí` with no added nuance at all.

As a though experiment: how would French refer to someone who died but came back to life?  Would it just be `il est mort` or would the passé simple be used?

Answer (score 3):

Whether compound past tenses such as *passé composé* are formed with *être* or *avoir* is a purely grammatical rule. It has no impact on the meaning, and in particular no impact on the “kind of pastness”. A *passé composé* with *être* is no more (or less) of a present perfect than a *passé composé* with *avoir*.

It's true that when the past tense is formed with *être*, the sentence is grammatically ambiguous: “*je suis* [participe passé]” could be a *passé composé* in the active voice, a present in the passive voice, or the present tense of *être* with an adjective that is an *attribut du sujet*¹. The choice of verb and the meaning determine which interpretations are possible.

Only certain kinds of verbs can have their compound past tenses formed with *être*: mostly state changes, for which “I have [changed to] state” and “I am [in this] state” are often equivalent. The default interpretation (inasmuch as there is one) varies from verb to verb. For example, “*il est mort*” (“he has died” or “he is dead”) implies that the person is still dead, because dying is normally irreversible, so the default interpretation is that it indicates the current state (*être* + *attribut du sujet*). At the other end of the spectrum, “*il est parti*” (“he is gone”) does not indicate where the person is now, because “*parti*” is not really used as an adjective, so it's clearly a *passé composé*. In between, something like “*il est sorti*” (“he has gone out” or “he is out”) is ambiguous, and only the context can tell whether this means that the person is currently out.

Context does make the grammatical interpretation change, and this is completely transparent for a native speaker. “*Il est mort hier*” (“he died yesterday”) is perfectly fine, and a native speaker would not consider this weird in any way. Similarly,“*il est sorti, il reviendra demain*” (“he's gone out, he'll be back tomorrow”) and “*il est sorti fumer deux fois*” (“he went out twice to smoke”) are both perfectly fine.

You can find examples of synonymous verbs, one of which takes the auxiliary *être* and the other *avoir*. For example, in many contexts, *arrêter* (to stop) can be indifferently reflexive or intransitive in common usage. These two sentences have exactly the same meaning.

> Son cœur s'est arrêté de battre.
> Son cœur a arrêté de battre.

¹  <sub>Verbs that take the auxiliary *être* are normally intransitive and therefore don't have a passive voice. However, dual-usage verbs do exist, where the verb can either be transitive and use *avoir* or intransitive and take *être*. For example, “*elle est montée*” is usually a past tense (“*elle est montée sur la colline*”: “she climbed up the hill”), but it could be a passive voice (“*la pièce est montée par un metteur en scène inconnu*”: “the play is produced by an unknown director”) or an adjective (“*l'affaire est montée de toutes pièces*”: “the whole business was entirely made up”).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think it could also have something to do with the term `mort` being used for multiple meanings, whereas other languages use separate terms. In English, `dying` and `being dead` are easily distinguished. The French equivalent is `mourir` and `être mort`, which leads to confusions when conjugating `mourir` in the passé composé. (Interestingly, German has the verb `sterben` which is reserved for the specific act of passing away.)

> As a though experiment: how would French refer to someone who died but came back to life?

One would probably say `il était mort`, the [plus-que-parfait](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/plus-que-parfait-de-l-indicatif-36.php) referred to something that happened before another action (that is also in the past): `il était mort, mais on l'a ressucité`

Answer (score 1):

1. Is être in the passé composé really nothing but an auxillary verb, or does it cause some sense of the present perfect to be evoked?

If the *passé composé* is used, that means the event happend in the past. The fact that what happened still affects the present can be a side effect but is not a grammatical consequence.

---

2. For example, to my foreign ears, I can't help but automatically translate je suis mort to English I am dead or Spanish Estoy muerto. But I'm wondering if to French native speakers je suis mort really just means I died/yo morí with no added nuance at all.

It doesn't, the context is everything.

*Je suis mort* is usually not a *passé composé* but a present (I am dead/exhausted) as opposed to *je suis vivant/en forme* (I am alive/in good shape).

> Je suis mort, je n'ai plus les jambes de mes vingt ans. (*présent*)

> Je suis mort en 1821, qui suis-je ? (*passé composé*)

---

3. As a though experiment: how would French refer to someone who died but came back to life? Would it just be il est mort or would the passé simple be used?

Either one can be used:

> Il est mort sur la croix, mais Il a ressuscité trois jours plus tard.

> Il mourut sur la croix, mais ressuscita trois jours plus tard.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... *être* as auxiliary doesn't automatically connote the present perfect any more than *avoir* does.

These fragments are more or less equivalent:

| être expression | avoir expression |
| --- | --- |
| Je suis monté | J'ai grimpé |
| Je suis sorti | J'ai quitté |
| Je suis arrivé | J'ai atteint |

However, there is a loose semantic grouping to the *être* verbs that interacts with the effect of the present perfect. Specifically, they are mostly about state change: birth, death, presence, absence, becoming, elevation more or less covers it. When the new state is still the current one, yes, you could say there is overlap with the present perfect: that is, there is no real difference between *Je suis mort* "I died" and *Je suis mort* "I am dead".

But not being able to distinguish them grammatically or semantically doesn't mean (paradoxically) that they are the exact same entity; one can be modified by locutions like *Je suis mort le 2 février* and the other by locutions like *Je suis toujours mort*, proving that they are lexically distinct.

When French speakers hear an *être* auxiliary, they hear it as one or the other, whether aware of it or not (and whether correctly or not), and would feel surprised if they then heard an adverbial phrase tacked on that didn't match the hypothesis.